# Process as Daemon on Init.d

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, daemon, init.d

I am trying to configure airflow webserver and scheduler to run. It is a python application.
I used "python setup.py install" and then using the shell comand:
(start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec airflow webserver) started the processes.
Everything works ok.

But when I create a daemon script, on init.d i am getting:

```
2015-12-09 13:41:29,808 - root - INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/pedro/airflow/dags
2015-12-09 13:41:29,810 - root - INFO - Importing /home/pedro/airflow/dags/simple_ecs_dag.py
2015-12-09 13:41:29,830 - root - INFO - Loaded DAG 
Running the Gunicorn server with 4 syncworkers on host 0.0.0.0 and port 8080...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 4, in 
import('pkg_resources').run_script('airflow==1.6.1', 'airflow')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 742, in run_script
self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 1667, in run_script
exec(code, namespace, namespace)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/airflow", line 17, in 
args.func(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 338, in webserver
'airflow.www.app:cached_app()'])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in init
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I imagine that the start-stop-daemon running or the python process are running under diferent users.

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Probably, you need to set the PATH to include all airlfow dependencies. I had a similar error of "No such file or directory" when trying to run airflow webserver.  I corrected my PATH variable to include /usr/local/bin where my airflow script was present. That fixed it.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1134